# suspend home server on idle / inactivity

Tags: power-management, suspend, nas, systemd, acpi

I've setup my home server to wake-on-lan and my router sends the wake-on-lan package when I try to access the server from anywhere.

Now the server should also suspend again after like 5 minutes after

- last disk activity
- last network activity
- and last considerable CPU load

Is there a an existing script / solution for this? Can systemd solve this?

Comment: I found the Debian package sleepd which works for the moment until I make something better based on data from collectd. However sleepd is unmaintained upstream. Joey writes he hasn't used it for years.

Answer (score 1):

You can try sspender https://github.com/mountassir/sspender

It allows you to suspend your machine based on pre-defined CPU/Disk usage, and makes sure the machine wakes up at certain times when you need it to be ON.

Comment: A configuration example would help.

Answer (score -1):

This is configurable in systemd with the logind.conf file.

`cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf
...
IdleAction=suspend
IdleActionSec=5min`

Check `man logind.conf` for more configuration options

Comment: I believe the Idle detection of systemd does only account for mouse or keyboard events. You might want to delete your response?